# Select a only first matching node in XPath

Tags: xpath

I have the following XML:

```
<parent>
   <pet>
      <data>
         <birthday/>
      </data>
   </pet>
   <pet>
      <data>
         <birthday/>
      </data>
   </pet>
</parent>
```

And now I want to select the first birthday element via `parent//birthday[1]` but this returns both birthday elements because bothof them are the first child of their parents.

How can I only select the first birthday element of the entire document no matter where it is located. I've tried `parent//birthday[position()=1]` but that doesn't work either.

Comment: What xpath tool/library are you using?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You mean (note the parentheses!)

```
(/parent/pet/data/birthday)[1]
```

or, a shorter, but less specific variation:

```
(/*/*/*/birthday)[1]
(//birthday)[1]
```

or, more semantic, the *"birthday of the first pet"*:

```
/parent/pet[1]/data/birthday
```

or, if not all pets have birthday entries, the *"birthday of the first pet that for which a birthday is set"*:

```
/parent/pet[data/birthday][1]/data/birthday
```

If you work from a context node, you can abbreviate the expression by making it relative to that context node.

Explanation:

- `/parent/pet/data/birthday[1]` selects all `<birthday>` nodes that are the first in their respective parents (the `<data>` nodes), throughout the document
- `(/parent/pet/data/birthday)[1]` selects all `<birthday>` nodes, and *of those* (that's what the parentheses do, they create an intermediary node-set), it takes the first one

Comment: >avoid using //

I'm assuming he has to use it considering the wording here:

>How can I only select the first birthday element of the entire document no matter where it is located

Comment: @igor: I was making an educated guess based on the sample XML input structure. Birthday elements that are not descendants of pet elements seemed improbable to me in this case.

Answer (score 4):

FYI: you can visualize the results of the various Xpath queries with the (free) [XPathVisualizer tool](http://xpathvisualizer.codeplex.com/).  Works on Windows only.

[image]

Comment: **Excellent** tool. Great for practice as well as when you are neck deep in trouble with XML!

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't appear to be compatible with Windows 10 64bit

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I admit this is horrendous and there must be a better way, but it appears to work.

```
/*/*[descendant::birthday and not(preceding-sibling::*[descendant::birthday])]
```

I look for all elements at the second level in the tree that have a descendant element called birthday that do not have a preceding sibling element that has a birthday element as a descendant.

Comment: if there were alternating `pet` elements with and without `birthday` descendants, this would match all those with a `birthday`, not just the first.

Comment: No it wouldn't because the preceding-sibling axis looks at all preceding siblings, not just the one prior.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:variable name="birthdays" select="//birthday"/>
        <xsl:value-of select="$birthdays[1]"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score -1):

try

```
//birthday[position()=1]
```

`//` finds nodes no matter where there are in the hierarchy

you could also do

```
pet[position()=1]/data/birthday
```

Comment: That gives me the same result, I still get both birthday elements

Comment: True but the problem is that when I run my xpath expression I only know that there must a couple of birthday elements in the document, I don't anything about pet

Comment: It still doesn't work with position()=1 because you are testing the position in the original document not in the resulting node-set

Comment: -1 because it is simply wrong. Well, actually the second XPath isn't, but I can't give -0.5 ;-) Will remove down-vote when corrected.